# How can i use the multi route "app.static()" from express

Tags: express

I wanna use two routers `express.static()` but only "/" router apply express.static() function.

I don't know why. help me pls.. below this is my project folder.

```
app.use(express.static("src/assets"));
app.use("/", globalRouter);
app.use("/users", userRouter);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to flip your `app.use` statements

```js
app.use("/users", userRouter); // Try to match 1st
app.use(express.static("src/assets")); // Try to match 2nd
app.use("/", globalRouter); // Try to match last
```

Express will now try to match from the `/users` route before matching from `static`, then if it cannot find a match in either `/users` or `static` it will then try the global router.

Comment: Thank you for helping me!  i'm solved this problem